# What, exactly are "is", "has", "was",etc

Tags: american-english

He *is* here.
She *was* absent.
He *has* returned.

Apparently, these are tense-base verbs, but there's surely a more academic term for them.  I am not a grammar, so I seek the aid of StackExchange.

Answer (score 2):

These are examples of [auxiliary verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb).

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can say these forms are conjugated verbforms. Verbforms of the third person singular (he/she/it) of present or past tense.
http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-simple-present-be.php

Comment: "Be" is also an auxiliary verb, even when it's the only verb in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

"Has," "had," "have," and etc. are helping verbs when used in the context of the perfect tense.

"Am," "is," and etc. are "being verbs," or "state-of-being verbs."

I wish there was a fancier term for them as well.